# Sort grouping field associated with taxonomy term by weight

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

I'm currently trying to figure out how I can sort the grouping fields(Taxonomy Term) by weight that I have setup on my views.

As shown in this screenshot below I have a grouping field that is associated with a taxonomy term.

1. Application Deadline
2. Scholarship Deadline
3. Class Dates

[image]

The only problem is that, it is not sorted accordingly by weight.

[image]

Is there a way I could the taxonomy terms by weight. I tried configuring the views but I can't seem to find the solution in solving my problem.

[image]

Comment: You have to add that term referenced field ("Group schedule" in your case) into "Relationships" under the "Advanced" tab on the right side and then under the "Sort criteria" on left sidebar add a field called "Weight" (must select that falls under "Taxonomy term" category) and you will a new "Relationship" field in the popup. Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually move the terms to a new order for the weights to change from a default 0 (you can click "show row weights" on the taxonomy page to see that they have changed after dragging out of order and then back into order; you only need to do this with one term to apply to all terms within a given level).